# Arch Linux: Wlan doesn't work, waiting for IWD

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, arch-linux

I installed AL from my usb stick, I followed the installation guide for beginners and everything worked. I connected to the internet like in the guide. But now after the installation it doesn't work anymore. When I try to go into iwd mode via iwctl it only says "waiting for iwd". What's strange is that I spottet the line: connecting dhcpcd or something on the boot screen. But then comes a line saying: a program runs already on dhcpcd or similar.

Comment: Try `systemctl --now enable iwd`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply run this command:

```
systemctl --now enable iwd
```